# Затемнение картинки и z-index (для неё и элементов над ней)

Tags: html, jquery

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка. Хочу, чтобы при наведении на контейнер (`price_stretch_container`) Картинка (`main_image`) чуть затемнялась, но контейнер, на который наводил - оставался такой же (не затемнённый). Вроде прописал `z-index` для картинки и контейнера над, но он все-равно затемняется вместе с картинкой.

---

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(".price_stretch_container").mouseenter(function() { // задаем функцию при нажатиии на элемент с классом slide-toggle
    $('.blocks_left').fadeOut();
    $('.price_stretch_container').css({
      'z-index': 3
    });
    $(function() { //затемнение фона при наведении на price_stretch_container
      var docHeight = $('.main_image').height();
      $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
      $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
        'margin-top': '50px',
        'height': '545',
        'display': 'block',
        'opacity': 0.09,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background-color': 'black',
        'width': '100%',
        'z-index': 2
      });
    });


    $('.third_pos').animate({
      top: '8', //Сдвигаю вверх
      height: '10',
    }, 300, );
    $('.third_pos').ready(function() { //Задержка(плавность) в 400ms
      $('.month_1').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_1_price').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_1_currency').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('.second_pos').animate({
      top: '-43', //Сдвигаю вверх
      height: '10',
    }, 300, );
    $('.second_pos').ready(function() { //Задержка(плавность) в 400ms
      $('.month_2').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_2_price').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_2_currency').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('.first_pos').animate({
      height: '10',
    }, 300, );
    $('.first_pos').ready(function() { //Задержка(плавность) в 400ms
      $('.month_3').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_3_price').fadeOut('fast');
      $('.month_3_currency').fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('.third_pos').animate({ //Сдвиг влево
      left: '-=30',
    }, 300, );
    $('.second_pos').animate({
      left: '-=300',
    }, 300, );
    $('.first_pos').animate({
      left: '-=575',
    }, 300, );

    $('.third_pos').animate({ //Сдвиг вниз
      height: '+355',
    }, 300, );
    $('.second_pos').delay(100).animate({ //Сдвиг вниз
      height: '+355',
    }, 300, );
    $('.first_pos').delay(200).animate({ //Сдвиг вниз
      height: '+355',
    }, 300, );


  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: 24.2%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #FF8080;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /*Нельзя выделять текст в голове (for Chrome)*/
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* for Mozilla Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer (не поддерживается) */
  -o-user-select: none;
  /* Opera Presto (не поддерживается) */
}

.header_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 55px;
  /*позиция элементов в header 'e*/
}

.logo {
  /*Логотип*/
  font-size: 30px;
  /* font-family: Times New Roman;*/
  top: 0;
}

.header_text {
  /*Контейнер текста в шапке*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

.header_text_inside {
  /*Текст в шапке*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: #263238;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.enter_text {
  /*Вход (текст)*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: #263238;
}

.enter_button {
  /*Кнопка входа*/
  width: 124px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #c2484c;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  /*отступ между буквами*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  /*Чтобы текст был по середине кнопки*/
  border-radius: 12px;
  /*Скругление углов кнопки*/
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.reg {
  /*регистрация (Надпись под кнопкой)*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: #263238;
}

.main_image_stretch {
  height: 545px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*Разрешение экрана меняется => картинка обрезается справа автоматически*/
  position: absolute;
  /*Для того, чтобы накрыть один блок с ценой другим*/
}

.main_image {
  /*Большое фото на главной странице*/
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.first_pos {
  /*3 цена*/
  display: block;
  height: 176px;
  width: 176px;
  background-color: #F58D4E;
  position: relative;
}

.second_pos {
  /*2 цена*/
  display: block;
  height: 176px;
  width: 176px;
  background-color: #91585E;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15%;
  /*Отступ от 3 цены (от first_pos) */
  margin-top: 43px;
}

.third_pos {
  /*1 цена*/
  display: block;
  height: 176px;
  width: 176px;
  background-color: #D46060;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 57px;
  /*Отступ от 2 цены (от second_pos) */
  margin-top: 87px;
}

.for_first_pos {
  /*1*/
  position: absolute;
}


/* 1, 2 для того, чтобы накрыть один блок с ценой другим*/

.for_second_pos {
  /*2*/
  position: absolute;
}

.price_stretch_container {
  /*Чтобы цены тянулись при изменении ширины экрана*/
  margin-left: 58%;
  padding-top: 95px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.price_1 {
  /*текст в 1 цене*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.month_1 {
  /*Ниже - отступы сверху в блоке с ценой*/
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 1px;
}

.month_1_price {
  position: relative;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.month_1_currency {
  position: relative;
  top: 34px;
  left: 2px;
}

.price_2 {
  /*текст в 2 цене*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.month_2 {
  /*Ниже - отступы сверху в блоке с ценой*/
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 1px;
}

.month_2_price {
  position: relative;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.month_2_currency {
  position: relative;
  top: 34px;
  left: 2px;
}

.price_3 {
  /*текст в 3 цене*/
  text-decoration-line: none;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.month_3 {
  /*Ниже - отступы сверху в блоке с ценой*/
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 1px;
}

.month_3_price {
  position: relative;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.month_3_currency {
  position: relative;
  top: 34px;
  left: 2px;
}

.colorful_blocks_right {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.blocks_left {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 34%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.ff {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.num_topics {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-left: -33%;
}

.try {
  position: relative;
  top: 545px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  height: 284px;
  width: 100%;
}

.try1 {
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 31.5%;
}

.try2 {
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 40.5%;
}

.input_name {
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: -55px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input_email {
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input_submit {
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: #CC6600;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  color: #974B00;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.inputs {
  margin-left: 37%;
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
}

.if_you_press {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  color: grey;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.agreement {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  left: 42%;
}

.agr {
  position: relative;
  left: -25px;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.ltl {
  position: relative;
  top: 580px;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrillic", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.topic {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 42%;
}

.topic1 {
  position: relative;
  left: -67px;
}

.learn {
  position: relative;
  top: -443px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 57%;
}

.learn1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;
}

.hr {
  position: relative;
  top: 220px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/no-main-picture-copy.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/screen_resolutions.css">
  <title>Главная страница</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="header">
    <div class="container header_container">
      <!-- голова -->
      <div class="logo">
        <!-- лого -->
        <h2>
          <a href="#" style="color: black; text-decoration-line: none;">SE</a>
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="header_text">
        <!-- Разделы -->
        <a class="header_text_inside prices" href="">Цены</a>
        <a class="header_text_inside feedback" href="">Связаться с нами</a>
        <a class="header_text_inside about_us" href="">О нас</a>
      </div>

      <div class="enter">
        <!-- Вход -->
        <a href="#" class="enter_text">
          <div class="enter_button">Войти</div>
          <!-- Кнопка входа -->
        </a>
        <a class="reg" href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a>
        <!-- Зарегестрироваться -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="main_image_stretch">
      <!-- Картинка на главной странице -->
      <img class="main_image" src="/img/main_image.png">
    </div>

    <div class="colorful_blocks_right">
      <!-- Для отступов при d экрана -->
      <div class="price_stretch_container">
        <!-- Контейнер с вкладками цен -->
        <a href="#" class="price_3">
          <!-- 3 цена  -->
          <div class="for_first_pos">
            <!-- Контейнеры с ценами  -->
            <div class="first_pos">
              <span class="month_3">3 месяца</span>
              <span class="month_3_price">1199</span>
              <span class="month_3_currency">рублей</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="price_2">
          <div class="for_second_pos">
            <!-- 2 цена -->
            <div class="second_pos">
              <span class="month_2">2 месяца</span>
              <span class="month_2_price">899</span>
              <span class="month_2_currency">рублей</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="price_1">
          <div class="third_pos">
            <!-- 1 цена -->
            <span class="month_1">1 месяц</span>
            <span class="month_1_price">480</span>
            <span class="month_1_currency">рублей</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocks_left">
      <div class="ff">
        <?php
    include 'db_of_topics_id.php';
    $num = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM topics WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM topics)');
    $answer = mysql_fetch_assoc($num);
    echo $answer['id'];
    ?>
      </div>
      <div class="num_topics">
        <p>Тем</p>
        <!-- Изменять при добавлении тем, как для числительного -->
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="try">
      <p class="try1">Главный шаг на пути к цели - первый</p>
      <p class="try2">Попробуйте несколько тем бесплатно</p>

      <div class="inputs">
        <form action=".php" method="post">
          <!-- Добавить php файл для обработки -->
          <input class="input_name" name="name" type="text" size="15" placeholder="Имя">
          <input class="input_email" name="mail" type="text" size="15" placeholder="E-mail">
          <input class="input_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить заявку">
        </form>
        <div class="agr">
          <p class="if_you_press">Нажимая, вы принимаете</p>
          <a class="agreement" href="#">Условия соглашения</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной проблемы я убрал z-index при обращении к price_stretch_container, вместо этого я поставил position:relative; :

```
$('.price_stretch_container').css({
'position' : 'relative', // было 'z-index': 3
});

$(function(){                                        //затемнение фона при наведении 
на price_stretch_container
    var docHeight = $('.main_image').height();
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
    'margin-top'      : '50px',
    'height'          : '545',
    'display'         : 'block',
    'opacity'         : 0.2,
    'position'        : 'absolute',
    'top'             : 0,
    'left'            : 0,
    'background-color': 'black',
    'width'           : '100%',  // было 'z-index' : 2 
    });
});
```

А у функции ниже этого кода: при удалении строчки z-index ничего не добавлял, ибо там заведомо было position:absolute. Тем самым решить задачу нужно было с помощью position (relative у price..\absolute у функции ниже), а не с помощью z-index. В чем была ошибка последнего - не знаю. Всегда буду рад ответу!